# Joomla 4-5 backward compatibility plugin not working

Tags: extensions, joomla-5.x

I was under the impression that all plugins which worked under Joomla 4 would work under Joomla 5 with the Backward Compatibility plugin. However, with one of my extensions (Minitek Slider), I get this error when I try to access certain features of the extension:

```
    Argument #1 ($db) must be of type JDatabaseDriver, 
    Joomla\Database\Mysqli\MysqliDriver given, 
    called in C:\wamp64\www\j5t\libraries\src\MVC\Factory\MVCFactory.php on line 274
```

Is it the case that some of the code which worked under Joomla 4 won't work under Joomla 5, even when the backward compatibility plugin is enabled?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Could you share the code that you're using to get a Database instance?

Comment: "Backward compatibility" plugin was a mistake from the very beginning. Nothing you can do expect try reporting the issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues).

Comment: Thank you for those comments. I solved the problem by reverting to Joomla 4 until the extension has been updated.